# `dyn Fn(String)` cannot be shared between threads safely

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust, so perhaps my approach to this is wrong, but I'm trying to write a function that returns a closure that generates an error with customized fields. The idea is to have each module call this function and customize the error with the module name.

The error struct and closure generator function are :

```
pub struct MyError {
    message: String,
    origin: String,
}

pub fn get_error_generator(s: String) -> Box<dyn Fn(String) -> MyError> {
    Box::new(move |x| MyError { message: x, origin: format!("{s}") })
}
```

I then try to assign this to a static variable:

```
static make_custom_error:  Box<dyn Fn(String) -> MyError> = get_error_generator("custom".to_string());
```

However, I get the error:

> `(dyn Fn(String) -> MyError + 'static)` cannot be shared between threads safely
> the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `(dyn Fn(String) -> MyError + 'static)`
> required because of the requirements on the impl of `Sync` for `Unique<(dyn Fn(String) -> MyError > + 'static)>`
> shared static variables must have a type that implements `Sync`

I don't understand what this means, and am confused since I'm not doing anything with multithreading. I would appreciate advice on resolving the error or a more idiomatic approach to creating an error generator.

Comment: Even if you were to manage to get past that error, you wouldn't be able to store it in a `static` anyways, because your function can't be `const`, since `Box::new` is not `const`. `static`s can only call `const` functions. You'll need to try a different approach, so what is your actual use case for this?

Comment: You know you won't do anything with threads, but the compiler doesn't. You can fix this specific error by adding `+ Sync` to the boxed type: `Box<dyn Fn(String) -> MyError + Sync>`. However as pointed out by @PitaJ you can't use `Box` in a `static` variable ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a1f40dacc7bdece0ae0964d3d477247c)).